# Вопросы моделирования: Entity или ValueObject (DDD)?

Tags: c#, ddd

Имеется сущность "Клиент" (`Customer`). Клиент может иметь 1 номер мобильного телефона и 1 адрес электронной почты. Телефонный номер, как и адрес электронный могут быть в двух состояниях - "Не подтвержден" и "Подтвержден". Забегая вперед, скажу, что все эти 4 параметра должны храниться в одной таблице `Customers`, дабы избежать лишних JOIN'ов.

Мой главный вопрос: **как смоделировать доменную модель?**

Атрибуты `PhoneNumber` и `IsPhoneNumberConfirmed` (как и `Email` и `IsEmailConfirmed`) выглядят так, как будто выражают нечто *целое*. Можно было бы определить ValueObject `Communication` с двумя параметрами `Value` и `IsConfirmed`. Тогда, класс `Customer` мог выглядеть бы так:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Communication Phone { get; private set; }
    public Communication Email { get; private set; }
}
```

Но как быть с тем фактом, что `IsConfirmed` это по сути - состояние объекта (что, если я не ошибаюсь, противоречит концепции ValueObject)?
Наверное, было бы удобно с точки зрения API определить метод `Communication.Confirm()`, который изменит состояние `IsConfirmed` на `true`. Что, опять же противоречит концепции ValueObject (VO должен быть неизменяемым после создания).

Возможно это Entity? Тогда эти объекты должны хранится в отдельных таблицах в БД? Это противоречит тому, что описал в начале ("...все эти 4 параметра должны храниться в одной таблице `Customers`").

Может быть, я сделал неверное предположение, что атрибуты `PhoneNumber` и `IsPhoneNumberConfirmed` должны является частью одного объекта?

Может быть, метод подтверждения средства связи должен находится в классе клиента: `Customer.ConfirmMobilePhone()`? Ведь, это клиент подтверждает телефон, а не телефон подтверждает сам себя.

Comment: ValueObject - это переиспользуемая вещь. Если у вас система позволяет "передавать" email и телефон от пользователя пользователю, особенно с сохранением состояния подтверждения, то можно использовать. Иначе это обычный атрибут сущности, без всяких ValueObject.

Comment: А в вашей ситуации в принципе, телефон и email могут существовать сами по себе или они всегда должны принадлежать какой-то сущности?

Comment: @sp7, в данном случае эти атрибуты принадлежат только "Клиенту". Сами по себе, отдельно от клиента - не нужны.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, спроектировать можно по разному.

Если подойти к вопросу канонически, то у вас телефон это `Entity` потому что он имеет идентичность и жизненный цикл. При этом, совсем не обязательно телефон должен быть корнем агрегации(хотя может, вдруг вы хотите отслеживать у телефонов смену владельца). Если сущность не является корнем агрегации, то она обязательно относится к какому то агрегату, в вашем случае к `Customer`. При этом, совершенно не важно где эта сущность хранится, в отдельной таблице или в поле у клиента. `DDD` вообще не накладывает таких ограничений. Вспомните по не реляционные БД, где все сущности агрегата вообще хранятся одним блобом.

С другой стороны можно смотреть на телефон как на характеристику клиента, который меняет одну свою характеристику (имею неподтвержденный телефон ХХХ-ХХХ) на другую характеристику (имею подтвержденный телефон ХХХ-ХХХ) и тогда уже у вашего телефона нет ни идентичности ни жизненного цикла, а это уже честный `Value Object`.

В вашем случае разница вообще не существенна, выберите любой вариант из двух и храните где вам удобнее.

Еще два момента по вашему тексту:

1. Не фокусируйтесь на том что `Value object` не изменяемый, лучше что это только характеристика `Entity` как цвет, размер или максимальная скорость.
2. То что телефон подтверждает сам себя в ООП вообще норма.