# DDD, aggregate root, entity, repository?

Tags: java, c#, c++, entity-framework, ddd

В книге Эванса написано что "repositories" должны возвращать только "aggregate root". А как тогда быть с обычными entities. Простой пример: есть класс City по определению это entity у него есть id и name его не уникален, как его получать, добавлять, изменять в "парадигме" DDD ? Получается что для каждой сущности нужен свой репозиторий а не только для корней агрегации?

Для примера кусок простого интернет магазина (ниже), получается и для tag и для region свои репозитории? потому что то как то надо их создавать, изменять итд.

```
public class Tag {
  private string _name ;
}

public class Region {
  private string _name 
}

public class City {
   private Guid _id;
   private string _name 
   private Region _region;
}

public class User {
   private Guid _id;
   private City _city; 

    // всякие методы
}
public class Product {
   private Guid _id;
   private City[] _cities; 
   private Tag[] _tags;

   // всякие методы
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Насколько я раздумывал над этими проблемами - Эванс говорит о следующем:

Одна и та же сущность/entity предметной области может как являться (в одних сценариях) Aggregation root, так и не являться в других. Как правило, почти всегда найдётся сценарий, когда тот или иной класс является Aggregation root.

В качестве примера я обычно привожу пример Contact с набором Phone[]. При этом я могу создать класс Phone, но не сохранять его в отдельную таблицу и не делать отдельный репозиторий.

Посмотрите теперь на связку классов Product с набором Tag[]. Если Tag - какая-то вспомогательная сущность, то смысла делать для неё репозиторий нет и можно спокойно сохранять строкой набор тегов в таблице продуктов. Если же у вас начинается какая-то аналитика и построение отчётов по тегам - у вас и внешний ключ появится с отдельной таблицей и репозиторий.

> получается и для tag и для region свои репозитории? потому что то как то надо их создавать, изменять итд.

Надо создавать изменять - ничто вам не запрещает создавать и изменять их без отдельного репозитория. При условии, что этот объект просто используется в сценариях, когда теги нужны только продукту.

Поэтому смотрим, что нужно в приложении, а потом уже подбираем подходящее решение (с отдельным репозиторием или без).

Этот приём (проверить, нужна ли отдельная таблица или можно встроить в основную таблицу) можно использовать в качестве проверки, является ли класс value object'ом и соответственно, нужен ли репозиторий. Не панацея, но часто работает.

Недавний [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/806811/213987) из моего вопроса: есть отдельный класс для точки на яндекс:карте, но репозитория нет.

Другой пример. [Паттерн Money](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/money.html) - типичный value object, отдельного репозитория нет и не нужно.

В подобных задачах всегда очень хочется создать репозиторий про запас. Но если бы вы отталкивались от сценариев использования, реальных, согласованных заказчиком (читай: подтверждённых рублём) - то увидели бы, что часто и не нужно столько репозиториев. Вы вот по-честному начали проработку приложения со сценариев или по привычке подтаскиваете CRUD во все классы?

Comment: В проекте (в коде) стараюсь описывать именно предметную область используя пользовательские истории и конечно непосредственное общение с заказчиком т.е стараюсь отражать в коде именно бизнес процессы, но, есть это но)) Вот из примера выше, есть City и Region, нужна возможность изменять и добавлять новые города (в админке), как это можно сделать без репозитория? но город явно не корень агрегации в этой предметной области, вкратце это типа интернет магазина, у товара есть город и у покупателя есть город, и нужно выдать товары в городе покупателя

Comment: @coder Админки ведут к CRUD-мышлению, тут вам просто такие проекты попадались, в которых без CRUD никуда и ведёт это к анемичным моделям и паттерну generic repository.

Comment: и еще  "у вас и внешний ключ появится с отдельной таблицей и репозиторий." у tag? он ж тоже явно не корень

Answer (score 1):

Репозиторий должен быть **только** у корней агрегатов. Озвученный вами сценарий по манипулированию сущностю говорит о том, что у вас `City` является корнем агрегата и этот агрегат состоит из 1 сущности. Не могу вспомнить источник информации где озвучивалась статистика, 70% агрегатов состоят из одной сущности.

Замечания по вашему коду. У `Tag` и `Region` нет уникального идентификатора по которому остальные сущности могут на них ссылаться. В таком виде они больше напоминают `value object`. `User` не должен хранить навигационную ссылку на `City` как и на любые сущности из других агрегатов. Только идентификтор сущности. Навигационные ссылки допускаются только внутри агрегата. То же самое относится и к `Product`.

Comment: Почему "User не должен хранить навигационную ссылку на City" ? City довольно простой объект, и скорее является свойством юзера. Просто это свойство есть у юзера и у продукта. На самом деле в базе у `Tag` и  `Region` есть id (удобнее и привычнее). Понятно что тэг нужен для фильтра продукции, вопрос как создавать, изменять тэг  без репозитория? Или тэг состоящий из одного поля name тоже корень агрегата? ))

Comment: Например, простой кейс, при добавление товара администратор может присвоить ему тэги (из имеющихся) или добавить один свой.

Comment: Потом.. Администратор может корректировать имена тэгов, для того чтобы исправлять ошибки

Comment: итд... в итоге получается что нужно создавать репозиторий под каждую сущность, 'Tag' 'Role' 'City' 'Region' хотя они по определению не агрегируют ничего в себе, просто свойства.. но репозитории  нужны получается

Comment: Сущность обладает идентичностью и жизненным циклом. Посмотрите этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/703619/181756). Если у вас city и region это только характеристика тогда, да, это value object. Но тогда вам придется менять это значение у каждого пользователя в отдельности. Это нормально. Не оценивайте тип объекта только по тому, удобно его менять у всех сразу или нет.

Comment: Теги можно писать прямо в поле объекта без выделения в отдельную таблицу. Это плохо ложится на реляционную теорию, как и вся концепция DDD и требует некоторого привыкания. У меня есть небольшая таблица у сущностей в которой есть тэги, они хранятся как json массив в виде строки и приобразовываются в коллекцию при загрузке объекта в приложение. Но, стоит серьезно оценить данное решение с т.з. требований к производительности.

Comment: Навигационные ссылки не нужны в пределах агрегата. Вся концепция DDD это только об изменениях данных. Если вам надо гонять селекты по базе, то DDD для этого подходит плохо. Приведете пример, где вам кажется, нужна навигационная ссылка на дргуой агрегат.